# Postal codes of China

Tags: geospatial, csv, postal-code, china

Where can I find geodata with postal codes of China with an open license (commercial use is allowed)? It may be shp, csv, kml. any geodata.

Answer (score 2):

They are hard to find them online but here is the list I suggest for you:

http://www.gfk-geomarketing.com/en/digital_maps/china.html

I suggest you to contact the Geography department at any universities in China. They may have them and they might have the most current postal code there.

It looks like China doesn't give out their geospatial data or datasets due to security issues.

University of Michigan China datasets has on their online but looks like they may be old or not. You might want to email them about it

http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283152&p=1886395

If not all of the above you want, the last resource would be the ESRI China and I am sure they have them. Their website is http://www.esrichina-bj.cn/

There is also ESRI China (Hong Kong) as well and their site is http://www.esrichina.hk/about/contact_us.aspx